# JQuery, How to read value of a <TD> by custom attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to data-value of a TD by specifying it row-id and col-id with JQuery. Any hints?

```
<tr>
    <td row-id=0 col-id=0 data-value="20">20</td>
    <td row-id=0 col-id=1 data-value="0"> - </td>
    <td row-id=0 col-id=2 data-value="0"> - </td>
    <td row-id=0 col-id=3 data-value="0"> - </td>
    <td row-id=0 col-id=4 data-value="0"> - </td>
    <td row-id=0 col-id=5 data-value="0"> - </td>
    <td row-id=0 col-id=6 data-value="0"> - </td>
    <td row-id=0 col-id=7 data-value="0,11">0,11</td>
    <td row-id=0 col-id=8 data-value="0,13">0,13</td>
    <td row-id=0 col-id=9 data-value="0,16">0,16</td>
    <td row-id=0 col-id=10 data-value="0,18">0,18</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please provide me more details what you want? Do you want to get the `data-value` value with `row-id` and `col-id`?

Comment: Yes, I want to get data-valu with row-id and col-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if you want to get the `data-value` for `row-id=0` and `col-id=4`, you can get it like this.

```
const dataValue = $('td[row-id="0"][col-id="4"]').attr('data-value');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet to get `data-value` of `row-id=0 col-id=0`: `$('td[row-id="0"][col-id="0"]').attr('data-value');`

Answer (score 1):

Offer a solution with the ability to enter data through `prompt()`, using such a selector:

```
$('table tr td[row-id="' + row + '"][col-id="' + col + '"]').attr("data-value");
```

With the indication of variables for `row-id` and `col-id`.

```js
let row = prompt("Enter row");
let col = prompt("Enter col");
let val = $('table tr td[row-id="' + row + '"][col-id="' + col + '"]').attr("data-value");

console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td row-id="0" col-id="0" data-value="20">20</td>
        <td row-id="0" col-id="1" data-value="0">-</td>
        <td row-id="0" col-id="2" data-value="0">-</td>
        <td row-id="0" col-id="3" data-value="0">-</td>
        <td row-id="0" col-id="4" data-value="0">-</td>
        <td row-id="0" col-id="5" data-value="0">-</td>
        <td row-id="0" col-id="6" data-value="0">-</td>
        <td row-id="0" col-id="7" data-value="0,11">0,11</td>
        <td row-id="0" col-id="8" data-value="0,13">0,13</td>
        <td row-id="0" col-id="9" data-value="0,16">0,16</td>
        <td row-id="0" col-id="10" data-value="0,18">0,18</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```